How do I make SQLITE query with limits, random and unions more readable?
In SQLITE LIMIT cannot be used in queries which you want to perform union on, so instead of writing something like
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE x
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 5

UNION

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE y
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 3

I have to write
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM Table
  WHERE x
  ORDER BY RANDOM()
  LIMIT 5
)

UNION

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM Table
  WHERE y
  ORDER BY RANDOM()
  LIMIT 3
)

Furthermore, if I then want to shuffle the data with another random I can't because inserting an ORDER BY RANDOM() at the end would give me Result: 1st ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set so I have to use the same trick and write
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table
    WHERE x
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    LIMIT 5
  )

  UNION

  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table
    WHERE y
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    LIMIT 3
  )
) ORDER BY RANDOM()

I think it looks pretty ugly, is there a way to rewrite it? more specifically my query is this one:
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    Caption.id,
                    caption
                FROM
                    CorrectCaption
                    JOIN Caption ON CorrectCaption.idCaption = Caption.id
                WHERE
                    idMeme = @idMeme
                ORDER BY
                    RANDOM()
                LIMIT
                    @numCorrectCaptions
            )
        UNION
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    Caption.id,
                    caption
                FROM
                    Caption
                    LEFT JOIN CorrectCaption ON CorrectCaption.idCaption = Caption.id
                WHERE
                    idMeme <> @idMeme
                ORDER BY
                    RANDOM()
                LIMIT
                    @numIncorrectCaptions
            )
    )
ORDER BY
    RANDOM();

It seems to me that there is a lot of overlap between the two queries (for example ORDERING BY RANDOM() three times seems unnecessary but I need my data to be randomly picked and shuffled at the end) but I can't quite figure out a way to simplify it. My tables look like this:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "CorrectCaption" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "idCaption" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "idMeme" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT),
    FOREIGN KEY("idMeme") REFERENCES "Meme"("id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("idCaption") REFERENCES "Caption"("id")
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Caption" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "caption" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

EDIT:
After reorganizing the query to use CTEs I do find the code a bit prettier, still I feel like there might be a more compact/efficient way of solving this
WITH CorrectCaptions AS (
    SELECT
        Caption.id,
        caption
    FROM
        CorrectCaption
        JOIN Caption ON CorrectCaption.idCaption = Caption.id
    WHERE
        idMeme = 1
    ORDER BY
        RANDOM()
    LIMIT
        2
), IncorrectCaptions AS (
    SELECT
        Caption.id,
        caption
    FROM
        Caption
        LEFT JOIN CorrectCaption ON CorrectCaption.idCaption = Caption.id
    WHERE
        idMeme <> 1
    ORDER BY
        RANDOM()
    LIMIT
        5
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            CorrectCaptions
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            IncorrectCaptions
    )
ORDER BY
    RANDOM();


You can use CTEs to make it more readable but I am afraid there is no otherway to do this in Sqlite.

You can add row_number as SELECT  Caption.id,  caption  ,                 row_number()over(order by Caption.id)rn ... and limit rows by where rn<5.  Random() function behavior in subquery requires separate consideration.

The syntax you don't like is defined by the SQL Standard, not just SQLite. You'll find it in other databases as well, pretty much unchanged. In my [very personal] view, I would consider quite readable.

It's not so much that I don't think it's readable, I just find it a bit verbose, using CTEs is something I didn't consider, it does make the code a bit prettier by reducing the level of nesting IMO, so thanks for the suggestion
